# Query Google Sheets Using Week Num to order dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates

I was finishing ordering timestamps and dates, and I can't quite get it to work:

```
=QUERY(Sheet3!A:I, "
SELECT D, SUM(I)
  GROUP BY WEEKNUM(D) ORDER BY D DESC
  LABEL SUM(I) 'Balance Semanal'
        SUM(I) '$#,##0.00'")
```

Please let me know your thoughts on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `WEEKNUM` as a [clause](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#scalar-functions) in a query.

Please use the following formula instead:

```
=QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(WEEKNUM(Sheet3!D1:D)),Sheet3!I1:I} ,

        " SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1 DESC OFFSET 1 LABEL Col1 'Semanal', SUM(Col2) 'Balance Semanal'format SUM(Col2) '$#,##0.00'")
```

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.